# Executable file not executing

Tags: permissions, executable

I cannot run an executable file, and it seems that all permissions, owner, etc. are correct. I don't understand the problem; I hope that someone will find a solution.

I'm logged as tux.

```
tux@tux-laptop:~/Data/Flightplan/FPP0.19Linux$ whoami
tux
```

Here is the directory where the executable resides.
The file that I'm trying to run is FP (the program is installed and owned by tux, FP is Flightplanpro for Linux)

```
tux@tux-laptop:~/Data/Flightplan/FPP0.19Linux$ ls -l
total 113588
-rwxr-xr-x 1 tux tux 23807760 2013-05-30 19:26 FP
```

When I try to run FP, this happens:

```
tux@tux-laptop:~/Data/Flightplan/FPP0.19Linux$ ./FP
bash: ./FP: Permission denied
```

I checked 100 times and I made sure that the flag "Allow executing file as program" is ON. Using sudo or root doesn't help; the permission denied error doesn't show up, but nothing happens.

```
tux@tux-laptop:~/Data/Flightplan/FPP0.19Linux$ sudo ./FP
```

I can run that program on my other Linux machine without any problem.

I'm running Ubuntu 11.10 (for various reasons including disc space, I cannot upgrade).

Comment: Have you made the file FP executable? `sudo chmod +x FP`

Comment: Are there other files that it might need to successfully execute?  They may be present but lack the permission.  Maybe try setting permissions recursively with the -R command on the directory to make sure it isn't something funny like that.

Comment: If you trying to run this from an USB stick, chances are that it is mounted 'noexec,nodev'. Remount it 'defaults,rw' and it will work.

Comment: Thkx for your help !

@Simplysimon; tried the chmod but same thing

@brim4brim,this is the only prog to run, no sub prog are called.

The program is on the drive not on USB stick or disc.

I already faced the same issue (with no solution) with progs installed without ubuntu software center.
I compared file permissions and properties with the one on the other working computer and everything is absolutely the same for what file and directory are concerned.

Is there somewhere any global security setting in Ubuntu ?

Thkx again !

Comment: Are you experiencing this issue still?